# VS 2013 Find and Replace multi-line regex (arbitrary number of lines)

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

In the IDE text editor, I want to replace this

```
var obj = Obj()
    .m1()
    .m2()
    .m3();
```

with this

```
    obj = Obj()
    .m1()
    .m2()
    .m3(),
```

Normally I would use this regex `/var\s(.*)\;/s`
How do I do the equivalent of the `s` flag in VS 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no equivalent ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)), you'll have to write it manually.

Search for:

```
var((.*\r?\n.*)*);
```

Replace with:

```
$1,
```

Also, there is a plugin that could be of help:

[Multiline Search and Replace](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/699CE302-B0D4-4083-BE0E-1682E873CEBF)

Comment: Thanks, that helped.  I had to modify it to this: `(var\s((.*?(\r?\n)*?.*?)*)\s*;)` replace with `$2,` and it works OK